# Pagination in Beautiful Soup (Python) When URL doesn't change

Tags: html

On a website, I scraped the street address, city, state and zipcode for every location on the first page using Python's beautiful soup.

However, how do I scrape the 42 pages that come after it given (1) the url doesn't include page numbers and (2) inspect --> Network --> XHR doesn't seem to work in this case either.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the website relies on JavaScript to refresh its content, you are going to have hard time scraping it using the traditional BeautifulSoup + requests combo

Usually in this case, I would first use Selenium (headless browser) to get the processed HTML and then pass it to BeautifulSoup for parsing.

The general idea is to

1. Get the HTML of the first page.

```
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get(URL)
    
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.current_url, 'html.parser')
    
    last_page = soup.select_one('a[class="last"]')
```

2. After scraping what you want in the first page, tell Selenium to click on the "Next" button using code like below

```
    # Loops until the browser loads the page completely and is able to locate the 
    # next button

    favourite_btn = 'body > nav > div > ul.menu.right > li:nth-child(1) > a'

    while True:
        try:
            w = WebDriverWait(driver, 600)
            w.until(
                EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, favourite_btn))
            )
            break
        except Exception as e:
            print("Error message: {}".format(e))

    driver.find_element_by_css_selector(favourite_btn).click()
```